# Get the hex code from the Foreground property of a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, colors, windows-phone-8

There is plenty of documentation on how to set the Foreground property of a TextBlock element out there. I cannot, however, find any way to get the hex code as a string (e.g. "#FF000000" for black) from a TextBlock's Foreground property.

I'm working with Windows Phone 8/Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that the `Foreground` property is set to a SolidColorBrush, you could just call

```
var colorString = ((SolidColorBrush)textBlock.Foreground).Color.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to get there using GetValue(Foreground) and all sorts of other workarounds.